# Is it necessary to convert factor variables to numeric while doing predictions?

Tags: r

I have a data in which 2 variables are factor variables. First one is 'Frequency' which has 4 values - Mly, Qly. Hly and Yly. Second one is Type which has values like Trad, Ulip, Term and Pension. Is it advisable to convert these variables to numeric like assigning values 1 to 4 and do the prediction?

I am new to datascience, hence the question

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. Please edit your question to limit it to a single problem. Also include sample data using `dput(head(df,20))` and sample code plus what your aim is. As it stands,anyone that answers is merely guessing as we have no idea what your ultimate goal is. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Nelson. Got answer to my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd better leave categorical variables as it, and do not convert them in numerical. The regression packages in R, for instance, are able to manage correctly factor variables (even without defining dummy variables). Moreover when you'll do logistic regression the response variable must be categorical.

Comment: In addition, converting categorical variables into numerics would actually introduce errors into a regression analysis because a numeric variable implies a ratio scale relationship within the values.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alession, SteveM and Nelson. I got answer to my query. Appreciate it.